# How to write Elasticsearch painless script to create new document in an index and at same time update another index's document?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, nosql, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

I want to write a painless script which can insert new document in an index and update the fields of another document in another index. Consider a scenario where there are two index (office and employee). office index have a field totalCount and employee has fields (Name,Age). Now I want a script which can insert new document in employee and at same time can update totalCount of office index. I am not able to find a way to do it.Kindly help ...